# Unable to perform POST request with retrofit android

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

While I am trying to perform the post request with retrofit, it is throwing timeout exception. While using postman the API Url is working perfectly fine. Is there any error in the code. This is my code:

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("accessToken", token);
    Log.e("Token Object", jsonObject.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Call<ResponseBody> callUser = apiInterface.facebookLogin(jsonObject);
dialog.show();
callUser.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.code() == 200) 
        Log.e("Token Object", response.toString());
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry! Somme Error Occured" + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

This is the interface:

```
//facebook login
@POST("/api/users/facebooklogin")
Call<ResponseBody> facebookLogin(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
```

This is the  Retrofit Client

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.100.15:8000/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

This is the successful postman request
[image]

Comment: Give a screen-shot of your postman request. May this will be helpfull to understand the problem .

Comment: Please check the screenshot I have uploaded. @PiashSarkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the request parameters as `RequestBody` as follows:

```
@POST("/api/users/facebooklogin")
Call<ResponseBody> facebookLogin(@Body RequestBody request);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("accessToken", token);
    Log.e("Token Object", jsonObject.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject.toString());
Call<ResponseBody> callUser = apiInterface.facebookLogin(requestBody);
```